# Convert language code to (dojo) locale code

Tags: java, javascript, html, dojo, locale

I have a system that returns me language codes, and I wish to use the same to compute the corresponding [locale code that Dojo accepts](http://dojotoolkit.org/documentation/tutorials/1.6/i18n/).

Is there a neat way to do this? 
(not sure what kind of mapping can be used)

Comment: What kind of language codes?  [RFC 3066](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc3066.txt), [ISO 639-?](http://www.sil.org/iso639-3/codes.asp), BCP 47 or some other kind?

Comment: there are various sources that work with different standards.

Comment: "Various sources" means nothing.  An AVI file of a parrot saying "Engrish" could fit that description.  Without knowing what you have as input, it's impossible to say how to convert it to the output you desire.

Comment: i understand that. so, can you tell me what would be the answer to it if its ISO.

Answer (score 1):

Given that you've tagged this with Java, I'm guessing you're getting a java.util.Locale.  Convert the underscores to dashes and make everything lowercase.